# How correctly mock class dependencies?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-mock

I've recently started learning how to use mock from `unittest` library and encountered a problem figuring out how to correctly mock class dependencies.
Below is the example i'm trying to mock

client.py

```
class HttpClient:

    def request(self, method, url, params = None):
        if method == "GET":
            return requests.get(url)
        elif method == "POST":
            return requests.post(url, body=params)
```

Here I inject the HttpClient object into the Post class

As I understood I need to mock `self.client.request` and this can be replaces with requests get or maybe in some other way?

data.py

```
class Post:

    def __init__(self, client: HttpClient):
        self.client = client
        self.base_url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"

    def get_posts(self, amount):
        response = self.client.request(method="GET", url=f"{self.base_url}/posts/{amount}")

        if response.ok:
            return response.json()

        return response.status_code
```

And now the testing part

test_data.py

```
class TestPost(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('app.client.HttpClient')
    def setUp(self, module):
        self.mock_http = MagicMock(autospec=HttpClient)
        self.mock_post = Post(self.mock_http)

    @patch.object(requests, 'get')
    def test_get_posts(self, mock_data):
        mock_data.return_value = {
            'postId': 1,
            'title': 'My title',
            'description': 'Post description'
        }

        response = self.mock_post.get_posts(1)

        assert response['postId'] == 1
```

So does when I set `mock_data.return_value` it actually replace the original response that is being called here `response = self.mock_post.get_posts(1)` or not?

Maybe someone could explain how this exactly works

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use dependency injection, you don't need to use `mock.patch()`. Just create mocked `HttpClient` object and pass it to the `Post` class. If your module depends on some modules which imported by `import` keyword, then you need to use `mock.patch()` things to mock them.

Besides, you can create mocked `Response` for the `client.request()` method. We can use the `Response` class from the `requests` package.

`data.py`:

```py
from client import HttpClient


class Post:

    def __init__(self, client: HttpClient):
        self.client = client
        self.base_url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"

    def get_posts(self, amount):
        response = self.client.request(method="GET", url=f"{self.base_url}/posts/{amount}")

        if response.ok:
            return response.json()

        return response.status_code
```

`test_data.py`:

```py
import unittest
from requests import Response
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, Mock
from client import HttpClient
from data import Post


class TestPost(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_http = MagicMock(autospec=HttpClient)
        self.mock_post = Post(self.mock_http)

    def test_get_posts(self):

        mock_response = Mock(spec=Response)
        mock_response.json.return_value = {
            'postId': 1,
            'title': 'My title',
            'description': 'Post description'
        }
        self.mock_http.request.return_value = mock_response

        response = self.mock_post.get_posts(1)
        self.mock_http.request.assert_called_once_with(method="GET", url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
        assert response['postId'] == 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

test result:

```
test_get_posts (__main__.TestPost) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
Name                                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/69751753/client.py          7      4    43%   6-9
src/stackoverflow/69751753/data.py           10      1    90%   16
src/stackoverflow/69751753/test_data.py      18      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                        35      5    86%
```